# Call Swift function in Objective - C issue

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a swift class with the below function:

```
public func testLogin(email: String, password: String, completion: (response: ServerResponse)-> Void)
{
}
```

I am trying to call the function from objective-c, but I am getting errors, can you please provide me the syntax on how to call the above swift function using objective-c.

I created a swift class instance, but the instance is not identifying the swift function:

```
swiftclass *instance = [swiftclass new];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `ServerResponse` is somehow derived from `NSObject` and change the completion type:

```
public func testLogin(email: String!, password: String!, completion: ServerResponse! -> Void) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your SWIFT classes visible for Obj-C you need to use #import <"product"-Swift.h>

You can find "product" in the Build Settings